# Problems with async/await and promise using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, settimeout

I've the following code that should have to works for a slider:

```
let timeOut, timeOut2;
over = 1;
let back = 0;
setInterval(change2, 8000);

 async function change2() {
  innerFront = slides[over];
  innerBack = slides[back];
  await setTimeout(change, 8000);

  innerFront.querySelectorAll('figure')[0].classList.remove('isActive');
  innerFront.classList.remove('slideshow__inner--front');
  innerBack.querySelectorAll('figure')[0].classList.remove('isActive');
  innerBack.classList.remove('slideshow__inner--back');
  over -= 1;
  if (over < 0) over = slides.lenght;
  back = over - 1;
  if (back < 0) back = slides.lenght;
  slides[over].classList.add('slideshow__inner--front');
  slides[back].classList.add('slideshow__inner--back');
}

function change() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    innerFront.querySelectorAll('figure')[0].classList.add('isActive');
    timeOut2 = setTimeout(()=> {
      innerBack.querySelectorAll('figure')[0].classList.add('isActive');
    }, 1000);
    resolve();
  });
}
```

My problem consists in the fact that the 'change' function seems not to be performed despite the Await for Promise. In fact, the subsequent instructions are immediately performed, and obviously this generate errors.
I still have doubts about the promises, which I am studying, and here I think there can be something conceptual.
Does anyone have the patience to explain to me where I'm wrong?

Comment: 1. You `resolve` the promise in `change` without waiting for the `setTimeout`

Comment: `setTimeout()` does not return a Promise instance. It returns a number that identifies the timer request. The returned value from the timer callback, Promise or not, is ignored.

Comment: 2. In `change2` (a) `setTimeout` doesn't care if its callback returns a promise. (b) `setTimeout` returns a number and it isn't useful to `await` a number.

Comment: `setTimeout` does not return a promise and is therefore not `await`able. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/14357 on how to wrap up setTimeout in a promise

Comment: Ok, I've to improve my studying... anyway, how I can correct the routine?

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo inside of `change2()` you wrote `lenght` instead of `length` twice.

Comment: Ok, thanks,. It's not a solution for the problem, but yes a typewriting mistake.